# Actions must be plain object. Use custom middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am using Redux,redux-thunk with react. I am returning an object but still getting the error.

**authActions.js**

```
export function register(){
return (dispatch)=>{
    console.log("in register action");
    dispatch({type:'auth_user'})
}
}
```

calling this action from **Register.js** using connect and props

```
import  * as actions  from '../actions/authActions';

class RegisterForm extends React.Component{

handleRegister = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("inside handle register");
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.register();
 }
}
var Register = connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(RegisterForm);
```

Error is

**Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.**

**EDIT 1**

Implemented redux-thunk like below.

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';


const store = createStore(authReducer,applyMiddleware(
                        thunk, 
                        loggerMiddleware
                        ),window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());


ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

**The code can be found on github using link** 
https://github.com/abhikulshrestha22/social-network/tree/master/client

Comment: Add a `return {}` after the `dispatch({type:'auth_user'})`.

Comment: still the same error. Didnt work :(

Comment: Try incorporating `redux-thunk`

Comment: It also happens when you're not adding a `redux-thunk` as `middleware` in your store. Try adding it.

Comment: I have added redux-thunk. please check the edit i made.

Comment: can you share the full code. The link you shared is not up to date

Answer (score 4):

You're using register from `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
this.props.register();
```

But it's just:

```
var Register = connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(RegisterForm);
```

So, calling register wouldn't work because it's in actions, `actions.register`:

```
var Register = connect(mapStateToProps,{register: actions.register})(RegisterForm);
```

Now, it should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**actions/index.js**

```
// with thunk
export const register = () => dispatch => (
   dispatch({ type: 'auth_user' })
)

// without thunk
export const register = () => ({ type: 'auth_user' })
```

**component/example.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { register } from '../actions';

const Example = ({ register }) => (
   <button onClick={register}>Register</button>
)

export default connect(null, { register })(Example);
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
const authReducer = (state=false, {type, payload}) => {
  switch(type) {
    case 'auth_user': return !state;
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're still having some trouble, here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/yqo75n896x

Comment: @mattcarlotta can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265169/css-position-absolute-making-the-textbox-go-down

Answer (score 0):

```
handleRegister = (e) => {
  ...
  this.props.dispatch(register());
}
```

Of course:

- Apply *redux-thunk* middleware
- In **Register.js** import `register()` action
- Connect **Register** component to **Redux** store with *react-redux* `connect()`

**EDIT:**

If this simplified code (without `mapDispatchToProps`) doesn't work, something is wrong with your question.
Maybe your action payload contains something that's not a plain object? E.g. promise returned by axios?

Code Sandbox according to your question, everything seems to work fine:
https://codesandbox.io/s/j2mny6rvnv

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the current setup that you showed above.

I think your `mapDispatchToProps` may be the root cause of this problem.

You should declare your connect likes this

```
export default connect(
  null,
  { register }
)(Register);
```

instead of (if I'm not wrong)

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    register: () => {
      dispatch(register());
    }
  };
};

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Register);
```

That's my guess. Hope this may help you.

Comment: Hi Tatsu, I edited the question and added the part where Connect is being used. Could you please have a look.

Comment: Change this `import  * as actions  from '../actions/authActions';` to `import  { register }  from '../actions/authActions';`
and change this `var Register = connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(RegisterForm);` to `var Register = connect(mapStateToProps, { register })(RegisterForm);`
Let's try this first, and see if it works

Comment: I tried using registerAction name also. It didn't work