# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. React + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-redux

```js
//REDUX

export const clinicAdd = async (name, address, semester, pay) => (
    (dispatch) => { dispatch({ type: CLINIC_ADD});
         axios.post('myURL', 
         { name, address, semester, pay} ,config)
             .then( data => clinicAddSuccess(dispatch, data))
             .catch( () => clinicAddFail(dispatch));
    }
);

const clinicAddSuccess = async( dispatch , data) => {
    console.log("Success");
        dispatch({
            type: CLINIC_ADD_SUCCESS,
            payload: data,
            
        })
};
 
const clinicAddFail = async (dispatch) => {
    console.log("Fail");
    dispatch({
        type: CLINIC_ADD_FAIL
    })
};







//using 

   onPress = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();   
        const {name,address,payment,semester, error} = this.props;
        await this.props.clinicAdd(name,address,semester,payment);
        this.secondFun()
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**I am trying to resolve this issue. Am new to react.**
*I want that when OnPress function executed it wait while clinicAdd ends and then execute secondFunction*

i'm using applyMiddleware(thunk) in my redux store

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Actions must be plain object. Use custom middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52799687/actions-must-be-plain-object-use-custom-middleware)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action function is wrong. Should be:

```
const clinicAdd = (name, address, semester, pay) => async dispatch => {
  await axios
    .post('myURL', { name, address, semester, pay }, config)
    .then(data => clinicAddSuccess(data))
    .catch(() => clinicAddFail());

  dispatch({ type: CLINIC_ADD });
};

const clinicAddSuccess = data => ({
    type: CLINIC_ADD_SUCCESS,
    payload: data, 
});

const clinicAddFail = () => ({
    type: CLINIC_ADD_FAIL
});
```

Comment: Could you point out what the difference is? I found it, but it took a while comparing to the original. It might be helpful to explain why as well

Comment: The difference is that dispatch should be async function, but not a custom arguments

Comment: i tried this but still same result

Comment: secondFun executes till this.props.clinicAdd ends

Comment: same :(( is any problem another functions ?

Comment: Updated other functions. What's your connect function?

Comment: export default (connect(mapStateToProps, {nameChanged,addressChanged,paymentChanged,semesterChanged,clinicAdd })(ClinicAdd));   its my connect